# SQL find non matching values in two tables

Tags: sql, join, match

I have two tables where I am trying to return a record from table1 that doesn't match a specific value in table2.  I want to know everyone in table1 that hasn't taken a specific course in table2.  For this example, I want to know everyone who hasn't taken course A.  The result should be ID's 3 and 5.  Thanks in advance.

```
Table1  
ID  Name
1   John
2   Jane
3   Joe
4   Jack
5   Jill

Table2  
ID  Class
1   A
1   B
3   D
2   A
4   A
5   D
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `LEFT JOIN`.  The query below will give you desired answer:

```
SELECT t1.Id 
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t2.Class = 'A'
WHERE t2.Id IS NULL
```

**Demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from table1 t1
where t1.id not in (select t2.id from table2 t2 where t2.class = 'A');
```

Actually, I prefer `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select t2.id from table2 t2 where t2.class = 'A' and t2.id = t1.id);
```

And you could also use a `left join`.